# jQuery draggable clones dropped into a sortable, then loses its droppable behavoi

Tags: jquery, facebook, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

This is better explained in:

http://jsfiddle.net/tRBaV/1/

I have two kinds of entities: containers and tools. Containers can be sortable. Tools can also be sortable, but only within one container.

In the top there is templates for containers and tools, which are draggable with a custom clone function. The idea is that the user can drag from those templates, create a clone of the entity, and design its own layout of containers with tools.

The DOM has already two original containers. They can sort themselves, dragging tools into them works, and you can re-shuffle them. If you clone a container, it also works as expected.

The problem is that the recently cloned container does not let a tool to go inside.

To reproduce, go to the above link: clone a container. Then try to clone a tool into all the containers. You see that it doesn't allow on the cloned container.

I've tried to trigger the refresh event on the sortables, destroy and re-create the draggables and sortables, with no sucess. It seems that the cloned container doesn't have the same data as the DOM containers, but how should I make sure it gets the proper behaviour?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't bother trying to debug your example, as it wasn't quite generic enough. However, I did attempt to re-create your problem.

Check out my solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/CdBye/5/)

I, like you, could not get any combination of the `receive`, `stop`, or `drop` events to refresh the newly dropped container. This is probably an issue that should be brought up with the jQuery UI guys.

So, event though it's not elegant, I used a brute force approach: Destroy the sortable, and re-initialize both it, and the tools collection.

Not the ideal solution, but it works. Hope you can use it.